# How to calculate execution and wait times for various scheduling algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

My homework is to fill in a table of scheduling algorithm completion and waiting times.

Here is the homework question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbTGG.jpg

The skinnier numbers in the table are the values that I filled in. I understand how the scheduling algorithms work, but for some reason my average wait times are not checking out with the average wait times that are provided. Is it possible that the average wait times are a typo, or can someone help me find an error in the way I am doing this question?

I am not asking for anyone to do the homework, but if you see where I went wrong (if i went wrong) and could point it out to me that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, please note that it is a bad style to provide all relevant information by a link. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Second, it seems that you don't use the correct definition of "waiting time". Waiting time is the time an arrived job is not executed prior to completion. I.e. for FCFS, job B arrives at 5, and starts its execution at 40. After that, it is executed till completion. Thus, the waiting time is 40 - 5 = 35 (not 40, as your claimed).